# How to efficiently develop a Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter

The title is quite a large question, but let me ask for a more specific problem I have.
I'm new to Python and I'm currently developing a text editor using Python and Tkinter graphic lib.
My goal is to make a Notepad++ looking text editor, I followed some tutorials about Tkinter learn more about widgets and so on. I came up with that :
[text editor picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qreS.png). One frame is composed of one text widget and 2 scroll bars and implemented like that :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

main_win = Tk()
main_win.title("Text editor")

#Notebook
container = ttk.Notebook(main_win)
container.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

#Frame
frame = ttk.Frame(container)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
container.add(frame, text='New1')

#Vertical Scroll bar
sbv = Scrollbar(frame)
sbv.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

#Vertical Scroll bar
sbh = Scrollbar(frame, orient='horizontal')
sbh.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

#text
text = Text(frame, undo=True, yscrollcommand=sbv.set, wrap="none", xscrollcommand=sbh.set)
text.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

#config scroll bar
sbv.config(command=text.yview)
sbh.config(command=text.xview)

# display
main_win.mainloop()
```

The next step would be to make some kind of function to create an actual frame with all its components to be called (when I create a new file for example). This where I'm stuck any advice on how to do that the best way would be appreciated.

Comment: first you could learn to put code in functions - and then you can run it many times. Next you could learn to use classes and then you can use `Frame` to build own widgets.

Comment: question for `best way` is opinion-based question and it is not preferred on Stackoverflow. Do whatever you want and you will learn which method is wrong and which is good.

Comment: @furas Ok I tried with one function wich creates the frame and all the widget in it,it's working

Comment: but how to access to a widget created by a function ?

Comment: in function use `return widget` and later `widget = function()` and you have this widget outside function. For more widgets you can use `return widget1, widget2, ...`. Evetually you can use `global` in function to assign widgets to external/global variables. But it would be nicer to use classes and `self.` instead of `global`